# Angular Factory returns token via $q promis

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to create a factory that will return a token to the controller.  This code only works as far as getting the token from the server but does not pass the token back into the controller.  The token just comes back empty inside the controller. Please advise. Thank you.

```
securityApp.factory("getTokenFromServer", function ($http, $q) {

    var token;     

    function getToken(userName, password) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:62791/token', data: { username: userName, password: password, grant_type: 'password' }, transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            token = data.access_token;
            deferred.resolve(token);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getToken: getToken
    };

});


securityApp.controller('membersController', function ($scope, $http, getTokenFromServer) {

    $scope.username = 'aharris1@test.com';
    $scope.password = 'SuperPass1!';

    getTokenFromServer.getToken($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function (data) {
        $scope.token = data;
        alert($scope.token);
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token } })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.members = response.data;
            });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not accessing the data in the right way. When using `then` chain of the promise the result is a combination of data, status etc.. (when opposed to success call back which breaks up pieces and give you data right up as the first argument) So i believe you should look for `result.data.access_token` instead of `result.access_token`

```
    .then(function (result) {
        token = result.data.access_token;
        deferred.resolve(token);
    });
```

And with you have you can just simplify your api method to return http promise itself rather creating a defered object:-

```
securityApp.factory("getTokenFromServer", function ($http, $q) {
    function getToken(userName, password) {
       return $http({
            method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:62791/token', data: { username: userName, password: password, grant_type: 'password' }, transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.data.access_token; //Return the data

        }, function(errorResponse) {
            return $q.reject(errorResponse.data);//Reject or return
        });
    }

    return {
        getToken: getToken
    };

});
```